# Help solving system of simultaneous trigonometric equations

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$x$ is all real numbers

$$\tan 3x = 3$$

$$\cot 2x=1/2$$

What I've done so far to the bottom equation:

$$\tan 2x = 2$$

$$2x = \arctan2$$

$$2x \approx 1.1$$

$$x \approx 0.55$$

$$\frac{3\pi}{2} - 1.1 \approx 3.61$$

$$\frac{3.61}{2} \approx 1.8$$

therefore $3x \approx 0.55 \cdot  3 = 1.65$ and $3x \approx 1.8 \cdot 3 = 5.4$

When I plug in $\tan 3x = \tan 1.65$ or $\tan 5.4$ into my calculator, I should be getting $3$ but I get $-12.59$ and $-1.21$. What am I doing wrong? Is the system unsolvable?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28tan3x+%3D+3%2C+cot2x+%3D+1%2F2%29                                                      Apparently on wolframalpha it says no solutions exist. I just want to verify that this is correct and the system really is unsolvable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan 3x = 3, \qquad\cot 2x=1/2$$
$$\tan 2x = 2$$
$$x = \frac{\arctan (2)}{2}$$
$$\tan\bigg[3\frac{\arctan(2)}{2}\bigg] = 3$$
This is not true, so the system does not hold

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$$

Let $A=x$, $B=2x\implies A+B=3x$